# Error resolving module specifier “three”. I am using npm to install three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using npm to install three.js according to official website of three and this is my project:

```
-> node_modules/three/
-> package-lock.json
-> package.json
-> index.html
-> index.js
```

**my script tag to load script:**

```
<script src="index.js" type="module" defer></script>
```

**my script:**

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
console.log(THREE)
```

then i open it through local server but at the end i get this error on my browser (firefox dev. edition):

> Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “three”. Relative
> module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.

seriously I looked everywhere for a solution but can't find.

Comment: Try `import * as THREE from './node_modules/three'`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried that and got **Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1:5500/node_modules/three/” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).**

Comment: You need to configure the server to serve the JS file as `application/javascript` not `text/html`.